# Can't make notice working with AJAX CRUD actions and how to make notice appear without reloading?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

**EDITED**


Tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked.

Here is code from create.js.erb:

```
$('<%= j render @website %>').appendTo('#websites').hide().fadeIn();
$("#new_website")[0].reset();
$(".alert").html("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %>"); $(".alert").show(300);
```

Here is my controller:

```
   def create
@website = current_user.websites.new params[:website]

respond_to do |format|
  if @website.save
   format.html { redirect_to  @website, notice: 'Website was successfully created.' }
  format.js {
    flash[:notice] = 'Website was successfully created.'
    render action: 'create'
  }

   else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.js { render action: "new" }
   end
  end
end
```

HTML of my notice-alerts:

```
       <div class="alert alert-notice">
```

Can you suggest why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are only setting the notice when responding to html requests, not js requests, I think you need something like this:

```
def create
  @website1 = Website1.new(params[:website1])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @website1.save
      format.html { redirect_to @website1, notice: 'website1 was successfully created.' }
      format.js {
        flash[:notice] = 'website1 was successfully created.'
        render action: 'create'
      }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.js { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you suggest how to make notice appear without reloading ?

Comment: use flash.now[:notice] instead of flash[:notice]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line

> render action: 'create'